# Why Sublime Text 3 doesn't jump a line when I write codes?

Tags: text, editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I write the codes in Sublime Text 3 code screen, it is continuosly slides to the right as in the picture. What can I do for this?

Please note that 10th line.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to activate word wrap only for the current view (the current file you're editing), just go `view -> word wrap`

Just in case you don't know where you have to add the setting, it is in you setting file, you can open it by going to `Preferences -> Settings - User`, and then just add it between the brakets (it's `json`)

Matt

Answer (score 2):

The setting `word_wrap` controls this:

```
// Disables horizontal scrolling if enabled.
// May be set to true, false, or "auto", where it will be disabled for
// source code, and otherwise enabled.
"word_wrap": "auto",
```

The default value is `auto` as shown here. If you add this to your own settings and set it to `true`, it will wrap for you,